# Grails 3 REST-API Anonymous Access Denied By ExceptionTranslationFilter

Tags: spring, rest, grails, spring-security, grails-3.1

I try to set up anonymous access to my API (Grails profile "rest-api", Spring Security REST for Grails), but the ExceptionTranslationFilter seems to invalidate the AnonymousAuthenticationFilter. Any configuration missing?

```
$ grails -version
| Grails Version: 3.1.5
| Groovy Version: 2.4.6
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_77
```

from http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/#_anonymous_access :

```
# application.yml
grails:
    profile: rest-api
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: com.company.api
    spring:
        transactionManagement:
            proxies: false
    plugin.springsecurity:
        userLookup.userDomainClassName: 'com.company.api.User'
        userLookup.authorityJoinClassName: 'com.company.api.UserRole'
        authority.className: 'com.company.api.Role'
        rest.token.validation.enableAnonymousAccess: true
        filterChain.chainMap:
          -
            pattern: '/api/guest/**'
            filters: 'anonymousAuthenticationFilter,restTokenValidationFilter,restExceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor'
          -
            pattern: '/api/**'
            filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
          -
            pattern: '/**'
            filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'
```

request/response:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/api/guest/1
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /api/guest/1 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 18 Apr 2016 15:45:59 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"timestamp":1460994359612,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"No message available","path":"/api/guest/1"}
```

error log:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/api/guest/1'; against '/api/guest/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/guest/1 at position 1 of 4 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
INFO org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion - You are running with Spring Security Core 4.0.3.RELEASE
DEBUG grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationToken@dc41564: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@dc730200: Username: __grails.anonymous.user__; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: false; AccountNonExpired: false; credentialsNonExpired: false; AccountNonLocked: false; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/guest/1 at position 2 of 4 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RestTokenValidationFilter'
DEBUG grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.bearer.BearerTokenReader - Looking for bearer token in Authorization header, query string or Form-Encoded body parameter
DEBUG grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.bearer.BearerTokenReader - No token found
DEBUG grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.bearer.BearerTokenReader - Token: null
DEBUG grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter - Token not found
DEBUG grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter - Request does not contain any token. Letting it continue through the filter chain
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/guest/1 at position 3 of 4 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /api/guest/1 at position 4 of 4 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/guest/1; Attributes: [_DENY_]
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationToken@dc41564: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@dc730200: Username: __grails.anonymous.user__; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: false; AccountNonExpired: false; credentialsNonExpired: false; AccountNonLocked: false; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
DEBUG org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl - getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] one can reach [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] in zero or more steps.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AbstractAccessDecisionManager.checkAllowIfAllAbstainDecisions(AbstractAccessDecisionManager.java:70)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.access.vote.AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.decide(AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.groovy:50)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.processFilterChain(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.doFilter(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:73)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Calling Authentication entry point.
DEBUG grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.bearer.BearerTokenReader - Looking for bearer token in Authorization header, query string or Form-Encoded body parameter
DEBUG grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.bearer.BearerTokenReader - No token found
DEBUG grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.bearer.BearerTokenReader - Token: null
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/api/guest/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/api/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Request '/error' matched by universal pattern '/**'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityRequestHolderFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/error'; against '/logoff'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RestAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter - Actual URI is /error; endpoint URL is /api/login
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 8 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationToken@dc41564: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@dc730200: Username: __grails.anonymous.user__; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: false; AccountNonExpired: false; credentialsNonExpired: false; AccountNonLocked: false; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 9 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error at position 10 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /error reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper - Skip invoking on
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper - Skip invoking on
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper - Skip invoking on
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration looks correct. However, given the following log line:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/guest/1; Attributes: [_DENY_]
```

It seems that you are missing an `@Secured(['permitAll'])` annotation in your controller/action. The request is unauthenticated because there is no security restriction defined for it, not because it's anonymous.